# What does “source” mean in Google Search?

Tags: google-search

`source` appears as a parameter/key in many Google Search referral URLs.

I've seen and/or heard of the following key values, as examples:

- `source=hp`
- `source=lnms`
- `source=web`

Does anyone have any idea of what it means? Does anyone have a more complete list of values and their meanings?

Comment: Been wondering as well, and found this link.
Not officially sure though. https://www.monperrus.net/martin/the+meaning+of+parameter+source+in+google+queries+and+HTTP+referrers

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2ecozy/eli5_when_you_search_for_something_on_google_the/ it is where you entered the search query - Google web site, browser plugin, etc.